# Is there a way to add or remove a category of a activity dynamically?

Tags: android

I am using `LauncherActivity` to dynamically decide which activity I want to display in the list.

```
@Override
protected Intent getTargetIntent() {  
  targetIntent.addCategory(xxx_category1);     
  targetIntent.addCategory(xxx_category2); 
  .........      
  targetIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  return targetIntent;
}
```

`LauncherActivity` uses the intent with specific categories to filter out those activities not needed.
However those categories are predefined in xml and activities must fit all the categories(not "or" but "and" all the categories) that make it fit the condition which make the `LauncherActivity` less flexibility.

So I just wonder is there a way to dynamically add or remove a category of a activity?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activity-alias lends itself to meeting need of dynamically 'editing' activities. By using aliases instead of your actual activity, you can create multiple aliases with multiple configurations. With an alias for each of the possible configurations you want to provide, you can enable/disable the aliases as needed thus adding/removing the icons from various views like the system application launcher.

**Activity Alias**

> The alias presents the target activity as a independent entity. It can have its own set of intent filters, and they, rather than the intent filters on the target activity itself, determine which intents can activate the target through the alias and how the system treats the alias.

In your case it sounds like you want an alias for each of these category configurations you want to hit. An alias should work well in this case I believe. I also note the dynamic configuration as I am not positive I fully understand your question so that may add clarity if I misunderstood it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html

**Editing an Alias**

> Set the enabled setting for a package component (activity, receiver, service, provider). This setting will override any enabled state which may have been set by the component in its manifest.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int))